# Bash Script with command line arguments which are files

Tags: file, bash, unix, command-line-arguments

I am trying to write a bash script which takes a file as a command line argument and appends the name of that file, the number of lines and the last modified date to the file. I am confused over how to access that file from within the bash script and how the command line arguments behave within the script.

Here's my script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename = $1
linecount = $(wc -l $1)
lastmod = $(date -r $1)
echo "$filename $linecount $lastmod" >> $1
```

I think I'm doing something wrong with the `$1` references. Generally confused about how to manipulate a command line argument that is a file.

Comment: What doesn't work about your current script?

Comment: there should not be white spaces around the assigment =. In other words, filename=$1

Comment: Unless you want `linecount` to include the filename, use `linecount=$( wc -l < $1 )`

Answer (score 3):

Remove the spaces around the equal signs. Assignments in shell scripts have to be mashed together like so:

```
filename=$1
linecount=$(wc -l $1)
lastmod=$(date -r $1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The positional arguments ($1, $2, ...) are the right method. You might run into problems with special characters (like space) and escaping, but otherwise your script should run fine.